# What source control would be best to use with my private gaming server?

Tags: version-control

I'm looking to version control everything, including sql server components, a client launcher, and server-side software.

I want to use an online resource where people can make updates, and make it easier to roll out any changes to players.

Most of the files are just text files, or gtx image files.

I don't think this qualifies as open source, so I don't know what to do.

I tried github, and have a free account there, but it was really clunky, mass adding every file to be comitted.

I really don't like subversion but if that's the best option, I'll use it.

The other people who will need access to the files will have no familiarity with any kind of source control, so I need an easy system for them to download files, make changes, and comit to the repository.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well last night I have been trying out Assembla.com with subversion.

Comment: Clarification: Are you looking for a hosted solution? Or a solution that you can host yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a wiki. It can track versions of your documents and is fairly easy for non technical people to use.

Comment: I need a source control, to host my files, and to allow others to remotely view/edit/make changes. How does a wiki help with that?

Comment: @crosenblum, you said your requirements were to edit text files and images, but to allow non technical users to use it. A wiki can act as a source control system, because it versions files. It is also easy for non technical people to use.